# Doubts with transitive closure in Alloy

Tags: recursion, closures, alloy

I am doing a model in Alloy to represent a subset of Java language. Below we have some elements of this model:

```
sig Method {
    id : one MethodId,
    param: lone Type,
    return: one Type,
    acc: lone Accessibility,    
    b: one Block
}

abstract sig Expression {}
abstract sig StatementExpression extends Expression {}

sig MethodInvocation extends StatementExpression{
    pExp: lone PrimaryExpression, 
    id_methodInvoked: one Method,
    param: lone Type
}

sig Block {
    statements: set StatementExpression
}

pred noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall [] {
    all bl:Block | all mi, mi2: MethodInvocation | all m:Method |  
    bl in m.b && mi in bl.statements 
    && mi2 = mi.*(id_methodInvoked.b.statements)  =>  
    m != mi2.id_methodInvoked
}
```

The problem is that the predicate noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall apparently is not working since the instances generated contains methods being invoked in a recursive way (even indirectly, e.g. m1 invokes m2, that invokes m3 that in turn invokes m1) and i want to avoid recursion.

The instances are generated through another model, see below:

```
open javametamodel_withfield_final

one sig BRight, CRight, BLeft, CLeft, Test extends Class{
}

one sig F extends Field{}

fact{
    BRight in CRight.extend
    BLeft in CLeft.extend
    F in BRight.fields
    F in CLeft.fields
    all c:{Class-BRight-CLeft} | F !in c.fields
}

pred law6RightToLeft[]{
    proviso[]
}

pred proviso [] {
   some BRight.extend   
   some BLeft.extend

   #(extend.BRight) > 2
   #(extend.BLeft) > 2

   no cfi:FieldAccess | ( cfi.pExp.id_cf in extend.BRight || cfi.pExp.id_cf in BRight || cfi.pExp.id_cf in extend.BLeft || cfi.pExp.id_cf in BLeft) && cfi.id_fieldInvoked=F
   some Method
}

run law6RightToLeft for 9 but 15 Id, 15 Type, 15 Class
```

Please, does anyone have any clue what the problem is?

Thanks in advance for the attention,

---

**Follow-on query**

Still regarding this question, the predicate suggested solves the recursion problem:

```
pred noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall [] {
   no m:Method
   | m in m.^(b.statements.id_methodInvoked)
}
```

However, it causes inconsistency with another predicate (see below), and instances are not generated when both predicates exist.

```
pred atLeastOneMethodInvocNonVoidMethods [] {
  all m:Method 
  | some mi:MethodInvocation 
  | mi in (m.b).statements
}
```

Any idea why instances can not be generated with both predicates?

Answer (score 3):

You might look closely at the condition

```
mi2 = mi.*(id_methodInvoked.b.statements)
```

which seems to check whether the set of all statements reachable recursively from `mi` is equal to the single statement `mi2`.  Now, unless I've confused myself about multiplicities again, `mi2` is a scalar, so in any case where the method in question has a block with more than one method-invocation statement, this condition won't fire and the predicate will be vacuously true.

Changing `=` to `in` may be the simplest fix, but in that case I expect you won't get any non-empty instances, because you're using `*` and getting reflexive transitive closure, and not `^` (positive transitive closure).

It looks at first glance as if the condition might be simplified to something like

```
pred noRecursion {
  no m : Method 
  | m in m.^(b.statements.idMethodInvoked)
}
```

but perhaps I'm missing something.

---

Postscript:   a later addition to the question asks why no instances are generated when the prohibition on recursion is combined with a requirement that every method contain at least one method invocation:

```
pred atLeastOneMethodInvocNonVoidMethods [] {
  all m:Method 
  | some mi:MethodInvocation 
  | mi in (m.b).statements
}
```

Perhaps the simplest way to see what's wrong is to imagine constructing a call graph.  The nodes of the graph are methods, and the arcs of the graph are method invocations.  There is an arc from node M1 to node M2 if the body of method M1 contains an invocation of method M2.

If we interpret the two predicates in terms of the graph, the predicate `noRecursiveMethodInvocationCall` means that the graph is acyclic.  The predicate `atLeastOneMethodInvocNonVoidMethods` means that every node in the graph has at least one outgoing arc.

Try it with a single method M.  This method must contain a method invocation, and this method invocation must invoke M (since there is no other method in the universe).  So we have an arc from M to M, and the graph has a cycle.  But the graph is not allowed to have a cycle.  So we cannot create a one-method universe that satisfies both predicates.

Try again with two methods, M1 and M2.   Let M1 call M2.  Now, what does M2 call?  It can't call M1 without making a cycle.  It can't call M2 without making a cycle.  Again we fail.

I don't have the time just now to look it up, but I think you'll find there is a basic theorem of graph theory that if the number of edges equals the number of nodes, the graph must have a cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much, C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, it solved! Sometimes we got stuck on a problem and do not see simple things such as the difference between "=" and "in".